# SQL запрос в mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

Помогите пожалуйста написать запрос, который будет возвращать мне id и role из таблицы Role по id Usera.

```
create table `User`(
   `id` int auto_increment not null,
   `name` varchar(255) not null,
   `surname` varchar(255) not null,
   `lastname` varchar(255) not null,
   `email` varchar(255) not null,
   `password` varchar(255) not null,
   `date_of_birth` date not null,
   `registration` date not null,
   primary key (id)
);

create table `User_Roles`(
   `user_id` int auto_increment not null,
   `role_id` int not null,
   primary key (user_id,role_id)
);


create table `Role`(
   `id` int auto_increment not null,
   `role` varchar(40) not null,
   primary key (id)
);
```

Comment: А что, мануалы не доступны уже? Юзай SELECT с JOIN

Comment: Это кто ж додумался в реферальной таблице `User_Roles` референсному полю `user_id` автоинкремент залепить?

Answer (score 1):

Вот запрос:

```
select role.id, role.role
from role left join user_roles on role.id = user_roles.role_id
where user_id = 1;
```

Comment: Типа сами задали вопрос, сами тут же ответили?

Answer (score 1):

Используйте [join для соединения таблиц](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_explicit_join_operations.html):

```
select r.*
from role r join user_roles ur ON r.id = ur.role_id
where ur.user_id in (...)
```

Только вы неправильно скопировали при создании таблицы `User_Roles`: поле `user_id int auto_increment not null` не должно иметь автоинкремент.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
create table Role( **role_id** int auto_increment not null, role varchar(40) not null, primary key (id) );
```

2)

```
SELECT User_Roles.user_id,User_Roles.role_id FROM User_Roles INNER JOIN Role on Role.role_id = User_Roles.role_id WHERE User_Roles.user_id = :id
```